# How could travis CI prepare the test environment for Ruby on Rails and its backend

Tags: travis-ci

My infrastructure is based on AWS, 3 for EC2 instances for Rails App Server,  1 for RDS (MongoDB), 1 for EC2 instance as Redis server.

Will the TravisCI launch similar services (eg. MongoDB, Redis) for pass the RSpec tests.

If not, what's the logic behind the TravisCI?

Would it be more practical to run the test on my real infrastructure rather than in TravisCI?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Travis CI fully supports [Ruby on Rails](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/ruby), and can launch the same services you need for the tests, so I expect you'd be all set. When you go to create your `travis.yml` file, you'll be able to set the configuration for your build environment, including setting up services including [MongoDB and/or Redis](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup). Here's some sample code on how that looks:

```
services
 - mongodb
 - redis
```

From a practical standpoint, using a separate environment makes it easier to ensure test integrity, though you do have to do the additional software setup. The main benefit though is that you get a clean slate at each build for all your tests and it's well away from your production code in case there's a problem.